# Read WAGO PLC Status Register with Structured Text

Tags: cpu-registers, plc, structured-text

I have a WAGO PFC100 PLC with a Structured Text application running. Now I want to read the PLC's status into a variable. From the handbook I found that the status register is `0xFA0D` which can be `1` (STOP) or `2` (RUN) ... but I was not able to find an example of how to read it.

Can anyone show me how to read the status register into a variable?

Thank you

**EDIT {** Ok, I just realised how stupid an idea it was reading the RUN/STOP state from within the PLC programme since it is not run in STOP state. :D

My point was to propagate this information over OPC UA, so now I checked if the OPC UA server offered that info by itself but could not find it so far. **}**

bf

Comment: Could you pleas provide a link to the handbook? Or provide something more as the Wago PLC environment is not familiar to me.

Comment: Status register of what? PLC? Or connection link?

Comment: @Quirzo The handbook can be downloaded here https://www.wago.com/gb/plcs-controllers/controller-pfc100/p/750-8101 ... Unfortunately the actual download link is not a permanent link.

Comment: @SergeyRomanov I mean the PLC status registers.

Comment: You could perhaps create a hearbeat variable (UDINT for example) and increase its value every cycle. Then read it through OPC UA and if it doesn't change in x seconds, you know that the PLC or connection is down.